# After deleting the google spreadsheet why i can access it via google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheet on google named creditionals. I can access it via google app script

for example

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("apreadsheetid");
```

now i delete this sheet from google spreadsheet after deleting that file again i access this google spreadsheet by its id it gives me true name and data of that file. why ?

if I have delete this file why google app script access it. it should show thw error that this file is not found. any solution will be appreciated.

[image: Delete spreadsheet]

Comment: Did you just move it to the trash or actually permanently delete it?

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UWmbh.png

Comment: That means you just moved it to the trash. Try deleting it permanently and it should not be accessible anymore.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach: Your comment is actually answering the question. Will you post it as answer?

Comment: I posted an answer but with the question it will probably be more helpful for future users to change the title from "deleting" to "removing" or "moving to trash".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving things into the trash doesn't delete them, like in your OS you can go into the trash and undelete the file (even if it is not yours but you have edit rights).

Scripts accessing that spreadsheet will only stop working when you permanently delete the file from within the trash.
[image]